# I have no idea what this means

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

Hmm? What's this? A room. Great. *Great.* As if the guards don't know I'm claustrophobic.

There's a strange text on the wall:

> Ribna tifmagta resru, sunte no, renler sludted dtednsehnun rurdal slutakdal danrtin. Hernite ridthet hori liridslu rtinrte. Ratslan tem netite nandethem. Themfmaglruhe tohreka de redesrongut, renta dtagfmagerroluneta no.

It is accompanied by another cryptic text:

> ## `y8oSQ`

The wall also says:

> Notice: There will be no hints.

But what does it mean? I'm confused. And panicky. And ready to get the heck out of here.

But I have a feeling it's just there to make me panickier still...

Comment: \*heavy breathing\* If you *can* answer this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The second cryptic text can be interpreted as rot13(l8bFD, naq fhpu fgevatf jr nffbpvngr jvgu vzthe :Q fher rabhtu, jr trg [guvf vzntr.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8oSQ.png) Frrzf yvxr ovanel?) EDIT: The second clue had been simplified D:

Comment: @oAlt rot13(Unun :Q Lbhe wbo gb svther vg bhg gubhtu.)

Comment: Is there a reason that 'there will be no hints' is hidden

Comment: Guess not. Fixing it now.